# Drupal 7 block hook after preprocess and before render with all blocks and blockclasses

Tags: drupal-7, hook, block, render

I'm searching for a hook that runs between hook_preprocess_block() and the render function in Drupal 7. This hook needs to contain all the blocks pre-rendered and the blocks classes in an array.

Tips of hooks that handle this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there is no such hook. It would have been very useful, though.

See an explanation of the D7 page loading process: http://artfulrobot.com/Drupal-7-page-loading-process-explained

According to the link above, drupal_render comes right after hook_page_alter.